# jQuery: .load() invoked twice?

Tags: jquery

I am really confused with what's happening. My code is very basic yet the result seems to be very complex :-\

```
$j.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

var $img = $j('.infiniteCarousel-vid ul li img:not(.noimg)');
var loadUrl = "http://shorelinerenovations.com/wp-content/themes/Narm/videos/load_vid.php";

$img.click(function(){ 
    $j('.vid-preview').load(loadUrl);
});
```

Feel free to visit the page where I am implementing this: http://shorelinerenovations.com/project-1 . The styling is very buggy as of the moment so forgive me. When you click on one of the image previews at the very bottom, you'll see the video is being loaded twice :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this script loaded and run twice?

`Load()` is in the click handler (the anonymous function you've passed to `click()`), if it is being run twice, it is probably being registered twice.

Comment: Tha ajax part? The code above is part of the single file plugin, I am certain it's not run/called twice.

Comment: Is a breakpoint on the line `$img.click(function(){` hit only once while the page is loading?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you look at the page, I've added a console log that's displayed when `$img.click()` is triggered. As far as I can tell, it seems to suggest that the logic is correct :-\

Comment: Install: http://getfirebug.com/ to Firefox and on the Script tab you will be able to see all the scripts in your page, then set a breakpoint on that line. To diagnose this issue, it is more useful to be concerned with when the function is registered to the event, not when the event the raised.

Comment: @jilseego, only seeing it `.load` once at that link now. Is it resolved?

Comment: Yah! Thanks a lot StuperUser! :-)